# Merge content of two tables with LINQ-to-SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables in my database

```
Table:Documents
Id (int), DocName (nvarchar)
----------------------------

Table:AccessLogs
Id (int), DocId (int), AccessTime (DateTime)
----------------------------
```

How can I write a LINQ query that returns the last 10 accessed documents and fills in the access time from the accesslogs table?
I have modified the Documents class in C# to have an AccessTime (DateTime) property. The results from the LINQ query should be of type List.

(My solution runs 10 queries, there must be a more efficient method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
var lastTen = (
  from doc in Documents
  join log in AccessLogs on doc.Id equals log.DocId
  order by log.AccessTime desc
  select doc
).Take(10).Reverse().ToList();
```

**Edit** - Then use the following:

```
var lastTen = (
  from doc in Documents
  join log in AccessLogs on doc.Id equals log.DocId
  order by log.AccessTime desc
  select new { 
      DocId = doc.Id, 
      DocName = doc.DocName, 
      LogId = Log.Id, 
      AccessTime = log.AccessTime 
  }
).Take(10).Reverse().ToList();
```

**Edit 2**

Assuming that there is a relationship modeled in the DBML then you can also only select the last ten log entries and then access the related document via the autogenerated `.Document` property.

As for your comment: The statements above cannot return this error as no new `Document` is constructed, instead an anonymous type is constructed which holds the necessary values.

Comment: The result List<Documents> needs to include the AccessTime property.

Comment: I get this error Explicit construction of entity type Document in query is not allowed.

Comment: Surprised that "on doc.Id == log.DocId" works. In a join, I've had to use equals so "on doc.Id equals log.DocId". See http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/equals-Versus.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a Foreign key relationship set up between DOcuments & AccessLogs, then Linq2SQL has already created the Document property in AccessLog.

```
var lastTen = 
    (from al in db.AccessLogs
    orderby al.AccessTime desc
    select new Document
    {
      ID = al.DocId,
      DocName = al.Document.DocName,
      AccessTime = al.AccessTime
    }).Take(10);
```

UPDATE: (I'm going to guess that you are using linq-to-Entities instead of Linq-to-Sql.) Then your basic premise (creating a `List<Document>`) is impossible.
The best you could do is a `List<SomethingLikeADocument>`.

```
class SomethingLikeADocument
{
     public int ID {get; set;}
     public string DocName {get; set;}
     public DateTime AccessTime {get; set;}
}


var lastTen = 
    (from al in db.AccessLogs
    orderby al.AccessTime desc
    select new SomethingLikeADocument
    {
      ID = al.DocId,
      DocName = al.Document.DocName,
      AccessTime = al.AccessTime
    }).Take(10);
```

Comment: I get this error Explicit construction of entity type Document in query is not allowed.